# Calculating cumulative for each month change - Postgres SQL issue

Tags: sql, postgresql

When I execute the following SQL query:

```
select yr,
       mn, 
       "%ind", 
       sum("%ind") OVER (order BY yr,mn) as "Sum%" 
from table2 
order by yr, mn;
```

The result is:

```
  yr  | mn |        %ind        |       Sum%       
------+----+--------------------+------------------
 1996 |  2 |   18.1818181818182 | 18.1818181818182
 1996 |  2 |   9.09090909090909 | 81.8181818181818
 1996 |  2 |   9.09090909090909 | 90.9090909090909
 1996 |  2 |   9.09090909090909 |              100
 1996 |  3 |   12.1951219512195 |  112.19512195122
 1996 |  3 |   31.0975609756098 | 143.292682926829
 1996 |  3 |  0.609756097560976 | 199.390243902439
 1996 |  3 |  0.609756097560976 |              200
 1996 |  4 |    4.8780487804878 | 204.878048780488
 1996 |  4 |    24.390243902439 |  268.29268292683
 1996 |  4 |   14.6341463414634 | 298.780487804878
 1996 |  4 |   1.21951219512195 |              300
```

This is an issue because what I am trying to do is adding each line of the column %ind correspondent with a given month, for instance 1996-3. Moreover as soon as the month changes I want it to restart adding from 0 till 100%. Consequently the ideal table would be:

```
  yr  | mn |        %ind        |       Sum%       
------+----+--------------------+------------------
 1996 |  2 |   18.1818181818182 | 18.1818181818182
 1996 |  2 |   9.09090909090909 | 81.8181818181818
 1996 |  2 |   9.09090909090909 | 90.9090909090909
 1996 |  2 |   9.09090909090909 |              100
 1996 |  3 |   12.1951219512195 |   12.19512195122
 1996 |  3 |   14.0243902439024 |   86.585365853659
 1996 |  3 |  0.609756097560976 |   99.390243902439
 1996 |  3 |  0.609756097560976 |              100
 1996 |  4 |    4.8780487804878 |    4.878048780488
 1996 |  4 |   15.8536585365854 |   84.146341463415
 1996 |  4 |   14.6341463414634 |   98.780487804878
 1996 |  4 |   1.21951219512195 |              100
```

What is missing in my SQL query?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `partition by BY yr,mn` to the window definition. As you did not define a partition (a "group") the window function operates on the whole results set:

Additionally you have to find another column to define a stable sort on the values for a single month. Assuming you have e.g. an ID column that is generated by a sequence, something like this should work:

```
select yr,
       mn, 
       "%ind", 
       sum("%ind") OVER (partition by yr,mn order by id) as "Sum%" 
from table2 
order by yr, mn;
```

Here is an SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/33838/1

Comment: This query is giving me 100% all the time in column Sum%. Do you know how to do it increasing from 0 until 100% then restart it again when month changes?

Comment: @SamuelDonadelli: that's the result of ordering by the same values as the partition is defined. Unless you have some other way of defining an order *inside* a month, there is no way to get a correct running total. See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/33838/1

Comment: @horse_with_no_name: Nice example, I created this id serial and it worked fine. Thanks. Samuel